# phone links not working in Android

Tags: trigger.io

I'm using tel:2125552345 format to link to a phone number but it doesn't seem to start the phone application. Do I need a specific permission set? I couldn't find anything in the Trigger.io App Config screen. Any ideas?

```
<script id="tpl_office_page" type="text/template">  

        <b>{{officeName}}</b>
        <p>{{addressLine1}}
        <br>{{addressLine2}}</br></p>

        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">24x7 Service Desk Toll #</div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" data-theme="b" data-mini="true" data-inline="true"><a href="tel:{{tollNumber}}">{{tollNumber}}</a></button></div>    
        </div>      

        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">24x7 Service Desk Toll-Free #</div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" data-theme="b" data-mini="true" data-inline="true"><a href="tel:{{tollFreeNumber}}">{{tollFreeNumber}}</a></button></div>    
        </div>

        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">24x7 Service Desk Email</div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" data-theme="b" data-mini="true" data-inline="true"><a href="mailto:{{SDeMail}}">{{SDeMail}}</a></button></div>       
        </div>

        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">Local Contact #</div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" data-theme="b" data-mini="true" data-inline="true"><a href="tel:{{localNumber}}">{{localNumber}}</a></button></div>      
        </div>  

    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" id="office_details">
        <li><a href="">Meeting Room Map</a></li>
        <li>Walk Up Location <br> {{walkUpLocation}} </li>
        <li>Local Escalation Contact <P> {{localEscalationContact}} (<a class="inline" href="tel:{{localEscalationNumber}}">{{localEscalationNumber}}</a>) <P> <a href="mailto:{{localEscalationEmail}}">{{localEscalationEmail}}</a></li>
        <li>ITS Regional Contact <P> {{itsRegionalContact}} <br> <a href="mailto:{{itsEscalationEmail}}">{{itsEscalationEmail}}</a> </li>
        <li><a id="#show_office_map" href="#" data-params="lat={{latitude}}^lng={{longitude}}">Office Location Map</a></li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

I believe this may have to do with the css formatting. Here's what I noticed

Following works

```
<p>This is a test: <a href="tel:+1 502 581 5000">+1 502 581 5000</a>
```

but this doesn't work

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">24x7 Service Desk Toll #</div>
            <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" data-theme="b" data-mini="true" data-inline="true"><a href="tel:+1 502 581 5000">+1 502 581 5000</a></button></div>      
        </div>
```

Comment: Could you post the full HTML snippet you're using?

Comment: It's dynamically generated from the template that I posted above. By the way, I'm using JQuery Mobile platform with Trigger.io

Answer (score 4):

To link to a phone number simply use html like this:

```
<a href="tel:123">Phone number</a>
```

If that's not working for you then what Android version/device you are using would be useful to track down the issue.